# missing FROM-clause entry for table in trigger function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, trigger, audit

I have created an audit trigger for table "product" that should insert data into "log_product".

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.insert_log_product()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
ROWS 0
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE')
THEN
    INSERT INTO log_table(
      operation,
      product_type_new, 
      product_type_old,
      product_name_new,
      product_name_old,
      vendor_id,
      available_quantity_unit_new,
      available_quantity_unit_old,
      delivery_time_in_days_new,
      delivery_time_in_days_old,
      change_date
    )
    VALUES(
      'UPDATE',
      new.product_type,
      old.product_type,
      new.product_name,
      old.product.name,
      new.vendor_id,
      old.vendor_id
      new.available_quantity_unity,
      old.available_quantity_unity,
      new.delivery_time_in_days,
      old.delivery_time_in_days,
      now()
    );

END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;

 $BODY$;
```

But I get an error message:

> ```
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "product"
> ```

The function is created using PGadmin 4.2.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_log_product_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
ON public.table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.insert_log_product();
```

The requirement for our audit table is to have each column separately, old and new.

Comment: Unrelated, but: there are many ready-made audit triggers out there. See e.g. [here](http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html) or [here](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/) or [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert 42 values into 41 columns.  Check vendor_legal_id.

Comment: That and there was one line with product.new instead of product_new